# Reducing round-trips to database

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms and trying to load data from SQL server. Here's the pseudo-code on how I do it:

```
connect1 = connect("database")
categories = connect.query("select * from category")
loop categories as category

     print category           

     connect2 = connect("database")
     subCategories = connect2.query("select * from subCategory where category = @0", category) 
     loop subCategories as subCategory

           print subCategory               

           connect3 = connect("database")
           items = connect3.query("select * from item where subCategory = @0", subCategory)
           loop items as item
                 print item
           end loop 'items
           connect3.close

     end loop 'subcategories
     connect2.close

end loop 'categories
connect1.close
```

As you can see, there are lots of round-trips going on in my script, this is fine when I only have few records but when dealing with hundreds or more, this takes forever to display the data.

What can I do to reduce the number of round-trips? I thought of getting all the data at once from the database then categorize them in the application side but is that possible?

Comment: Do it all in one query. Take a look at [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This question is better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @nunespascal Why CTE?

Comment: CTE so that you can recursively get the subcategories.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you get all data you need by one query with joins and then filter in on a client-side; Or other way you can do it (it there's not too much data) is getting data as xml, deserialize it to ienumerable an iterate through.

As i see it you do

```
categories = connect.query("select * from category");
```

so all you need is:

```
whole_data = connect.query("select * from category c inner join subCategory sc on c.id = sc.id inner join item i on i.id = si.id") /*or some kind of*/
/*let me think that whole_data is a list of objects, not a dataset*/
categories = whole_data.Distinct(d => d.category);
subCategories = whole_data.Distinct(d => d.subCategories);
/*and then do your loops*/
```

c# code for manual mapping might be like that:

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select * from ...";

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var a = reader.GetInt32(0);
                var b = reader.GetString(1);
                /*so basically you read all fields that you get from DB and build object here, then you add it to List or any other kind of collection*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's what I thought but the question is, how? There is this thing, a library or class that I need to query a result set in the application side.

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help but I'm not looking for pseudo-codes or actual codes, if you know any library or class that I can use to query the "whole_data", what would it be?

Comment: You might want to look for any kind of ORM like nhibernate, or entity framework, or (i use it) mini-ORM dapper. Another way is to map data manually, let me post some codez in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the latency to your database, making the connections, even if pooled, can take a long time.  To avoid that over head, make all your connections outside of the loops.  That is, don't nest the connections.  Instead, structure it like this:

```
Connect1 = connect("database")
Connect2 = connect("database")
Connect3 = connect("database")

sql 1 nest
    sql 2 nest
        sql 3 nest
        end nest
    end nest
end nest

close connections.
```

If you have 10 entries per loop, and a connection takes 10 mSec, you will spend 10 x 10 x 10 = 1000 mS just doing connections.  Take them outside the nest, then you spend only 30 mS making connections.  Close your datareader at the completion of each nest so the connection can be reused.

Of course, for the example you showed, doing a single query is the best solution.
But, if your query is selective and you need to perform some business logic that cannot be combined in the query, then always move your connections outside of the loop.